# How do i process whole SQL statement in mybatis?

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I'm trying to make simple SQL editor using JAVA.

Problem is [mybatis mapper](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html) xml uses #{}..
I want to use whole sql statement itself without formatting.
Is it possible?

If I wanna get answer about Sql statement what I received from user, which way should i use?
Is there any way to process whole SQL statement in Java ?

※ I tried mybatis '${sql whole statement}' but i heard this way is vulnerable to security...

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You can use a Mapper XML File. There you can use any `<select>` or `<insert>`, `<update>` or `<delete>` tags to run any typical or complex SQL statement. It also has all the flexibility to call stored procedures or functions. See https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html

Comment: If I received from SQL statement from web(ex: javascript : input box) to Java, can I execute SQL statement itself? Is there any way to execute SQL statement without using string format? Thank you for your comment sir.

Comment: You are receiving a SQL statement from the web (a `<form>` parameter probably), not assembled in the server. And you want to run it. In terms of security this is very risky. Some third party can intercept the HTTPS requests, modify your SQL statement, compromise, and damage your database. MyBatis, however, can still run it using `<select>${unsafe_query}</select>`. However, I strongly suggest you re-architect your solution.. This is very, very unsafe.